How to disable Entry Widget when clicked outside of Entry Box
I'm making a GUI application in Python 3 with the Tkinter module. My app includes an Entry Widget that the user can type into. The only problem is that when the user is done typing and clicks outside of the Entry Box, the Entry Box doesn't get disabled. I tried to do something with the state parameter of the Entry Widget but I didn't know what to do with it.
How would I go about implementing this feature?
Here's what my code looks like:
from tkinter import*

tk = Tk()
tk.minsize(250, 300)
tk.resizable(False, False)

val = StringVar()
val.set(100)

user_input = Entry(tk, textvariable=val, width=22)

user_input.place(x=100, y=83)

tk.mainloop()


Short answer: Don't do this. Longer answer: "when the user is done typing and clicks outside of the Entry Box, the Entry Box doesn't get disabled" - This behavior is not the default, so you'd have to implement it yourself. That said, I'd advise against this as bad UX. What happens if the user makes a mistake when editing the Entry? If it's disabled once it loses focus, then the user can't interact with it again. As an aside, you should always try to provide a [mre] in the body of your question - remember, we can't help you fix a problem if we can't see what you've tried.

No I meant that the user can click on it again and fix their mistake after clicking outside of the box.

If that's the idea, why disable it in the first place? Please [edit] your question to add some code so we can get a better understanding of what you're after.

Okay I've added a shortened version of code for understanding

It's unclear what you're asking. What's the point of disabling it? If it doesn't have keyboard focus then the user can't type in it. If you want the user to be able to correct mistakes then you shouldn't disable it because you disable the ability to fix mistakes.

I guess my question is still "Why do you want this feature?" What problem are you having that this feature will solve? The issue I see is that, as I said, if you disable the Entry on blur, then it can't be focused again by the user and will remain disabled. If you do still want the user to be able to edit the Entry, then why disable it in the first place?

as a user I would hate your idea.

you can bind() function to widget for some event - like python - Tkinter - window focus loss event - Stack Overflow - so you may try to use it if you really need it.

You may use bind() to assign function to Entry which will be executed when there will be event <FocusOut>. And this function can disable Entry.
But disabled widget can't be focused and function assigned to <FocusIn> will not work.
So it will be disabled all time and you will need other method (e.g. button) to activate it back.
And this seems useless and it can be annoying for users.
Based on code from Tkinter - window focus loss event
import tkinter as tk

def on_focus_out(event):
    label.configure(text="I DON'T have focus")
    entry.config(state='disabled')

def on_focus_in(event):
    label.configure(text="I have focus")
    entry.config(state='normal')
    
def on_button_click():
    entry.config(state='normal')
        
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="HELLO")
label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
entry.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

button = tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=on_button_click)
button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

entry.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in)
entry.bind("<FocusOut>", on_focus_out)

root.mainloop()

As a user I wouldn't like idea with disabled entry. But you can still use this code to do something different - e.g. you can check if text is valid and change background for red.
import tkinter as tk

def on_focus_out(event):
    text = event.widget.get()
    if len(text) < 5:
        label.configure(text="Too short - at least 5 chars")
        event.widget['bg'] = '#ffa0a0'
    else:
        label.configure(text="OK")

def on_focus_in(event):
    event.widget['bg'] = original_color

    
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="HELLO")
label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
entry1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

entry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
entry2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

entry3 = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
entry3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

original_color = entry1['bg']
print(original_color)

button = tk.Button(root, text="EXIT", command=root.destroy)
button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

entry1.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in)
entry1.bind("<FocusOut>", on_focus_out)

entry2.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in)
entry2.bind("<FocusOut>", on_focus_out)

entry3.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in)
entry3.bind("<FocusOut>", on_focus_out)

root.mainloop()


Meanwhile I created version with class MyEntry
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class MyEntry(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="HELLO")
        self.label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.entry.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.original_color = self.entry['bg']
        
        self.entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        self.entry.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)

    def on_focus_out(self, event):
        text = self.entry.get()
        if len(text) < 5:
            self.label.configure(text="Too short - at least 5 chars")
            self.entry['bg'] = '#ffa0a0'
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="OK")

    def on_focus_in(self, event):
        self.entry['bg'] = self.original_color
    
# --- main ---
    
root = tk.Tk()

widget1 = MyEntry(root)
widget1.pack()

widget2 = MyEntry(root)
widget2.pack()

widget3 = MyEntry(root)
widget3.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="EXIT", command=root.destroy)
button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()


line 15, in on_button_click
entry.config(state='normal')
^^^^^
NameError: name 'entry' is not defined. Did you mean: 'entry1'?

@toyotaSupra frankly, I didn't use this button at all when I was creating code - so I forgot this part :) In my last version (which is only on my disk) I set command=root.destroy and removed function on_button_click. Now I fixed it in answer. Thank you.

Since '<FocusOut>' is not always triggering the function, I've bound with '<Leave>'. Added a button to edit the user_entry so that the user can edit the input if they had done any mistake while typing first time.
from tkinter import *    

# Checks whether any input given and then, disables user_input
def disable_input(event):
    if user_input.get() != '':
        user_input['state'] = DISABLED

# triggered by button to make the user_input enabled and set focus inside
def edit_text():
    user_input['state'] = NORMAL
    user_input.focus_set()

tk = Tk()
tk.minsize(250, 300)
tk.resizable(False, False)

user_input = Entry(tk, width=22)
user_input.place(x=100, y=83)

btn = Button(tk, text="Edit input", command=edit_text)
btn.place(x=100, y=110)


# binds '<Leave>' and the function disable_input
user_input.bind('<Leave>', disable_input)

tk.mainloop()


Much better than @furas's answer.

I think what you want is to make the entry box to lose the keyboard focus when clicking outside it, i.e. clicking the main window for your case.
Then you need to bind <Button-1> on the main window and call tk.focus_set() inside the callback:
def on_click(event):
    # only do it when the widget that triggers the event is the main window
    if event.widget is tk:
        tk.focus_set()

tk.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)


Or simply:
# move the keyboard focus to the widget that triggers the event
tk.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: e.widget.focus_set())


OP wants to disable Entry Widget when clicked outside of Entry Box
